# Is there any way to my tooltip remain visible despite of using overflow-x:auto; property in the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in web-development learning html and css. As you can see in this pic I am re-creating the Facebook **people you may know** section in which there are multiple accounts as we scroll from left to right

[image]

to achieve this I have given the `overflow-x:auto;` property to my parent div (which has a `bg-color:gray`). when I hover in to accounts name I need a tooltip to appear in which there will be further info about the account and according to my design that tooltip should be on a little left side but since I've used the `overflow-x:auto;` property in the parent div, the tooltip is not visible. How do I solve this?
I want to scroll horizontally but also want my tooltip to be visible

I thought of increasing the z-index of the tooltip but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)